# Incrementing a variable N times and storing the answer in a matrix

Tags: r, increment

I have a simple formula that includes two variables, azimuth and beamwidth. Azimuth represents the direction/orientation of an antenna given by an integer value from 0 degrees to 360 degrees. The beamwidth represents the horizontal width of the antenna, similar to the horizontal width of a piece of apple pie.

```
cellPoints <- (Azimuth - (Beamwidth/2))%%360
```

If my azimuth/bearing is 120 degrees and my beamwidth is 60 degress that means I have edges at 120-(60/2) and 120+(60/2). Since my extreme left angle is 90 degrees I wish to increment from 90 by beamwidth/6 until I reach 150 degrees.

I would like to store the results in a matrix. This is simple to achieve for a once off calculation but my azimuths and beamwidths take on many different values. Should this be done using for loops or using one of the apply family?

My data frame looks as follows:

My table looks as follows:

```
Cell Name   Azimuth Beamwidth                 cellPoints
ABCDU09A3     120      65       87.5 98.33 109.16 119.99 130.82 141.65 152.48
ABCDU09B3     240      65   
ABCDU09C3      0       65
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a sequence like this?

```
edges = seq(Azimuth - Beamwidth/2, Azimuth + Beamwidth/2, Beamwidth/6)%%360
```

Result for

```
Azimuth = 120
Beamwidth = 60

> edges
[1]  90 100 110 120 130 140 150
```

---

If you have several Azimuth values and a corresponding Beamwidth then do:

```
Azimuth = c(120,300,40)
Beamwidth = c(60,30,6)

df = data.frame(Azimuth, Beamwidth)

points = apply(df,1, function(x) seq(x[1]-x[2]/2,x[1]+x[2]/2,x[2]/6) %% 360)

>points
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   90  285   37
[2,]  100  290   38
[3,]  110  295   39
[4,]  120  300   40
[5,]  130  305   41
[6,]  140  310   42
[7,]  150  315   43
```

---

**EDIT**

Using your dataframe, you should do:

```
cellNames = c("ABCDU09A3","ABCDU09B3","ABCDU09C3")
Azimuth = c(120,240,0)
Beamwidth = c(65,65,65)

df = data.frame(cellNames,Azimuth, Beamwidth)

points = apply(df[,2:3],1, function(x) seq(x[1]-x[2]/2,x[1]+x[2]/2,x[2]/6) %% 360)

df = cbind(df,t(points))
```

**Result:**

```
  cellNames Azimuth Beamwidth     1         2        3   4         5         6     7
1 ABCDU09A3     120        65  87.5  98.33333 109.1667 120 130.83333 141.66667 152.5
2 ABCDU09B3     240        65 207.5 218.33333 229.1667 240 250.83333 261.66667 272.5
3 ABCDU09C3       0        65 327.5 338.33333 349.1667   0  10.83333  21.66667  32.5
```

As you can see, `function(x)` in the apply function will take as `x` parameters each row of the data frame `df` but only columns 2 and 3 (Azimuth and Bandwidth).

The result of the apply function is stored in columns, in order to bind it to `df` you need to have the results by row, so transpose it using `t(points)`.

Comment: please excuse my ignorance what does function(x) do/represent? In the help info for apply a function is to applied such as +, - %*% etc. Also, regarding several azimuths I actually have 13000 azimuths and beamwidths in these columns in my DF. How can I calculate these points for all 13000 cells?

Comment: The 3 arguments of `apply` in my answer are: the data frame `df`, the dimension it will take from df, in this case is 1 or rows (2 for columns) and 3rd the function that will be applied.  The argument `x` in `function(x){...} ` will be one entire row at a time. `x[1]` is the first element in the row (Azimuth) and `x[2]` the 2nd (Beamwidth). Each output of `f(x)` is a vector of 7 elements (you wanted 7 stops). The final result is a matrix of 7 rows by N columns, where N are your different Azimuth, Beamwidth pairs. Results are stored in columns.

Comment: thank you so much for your time and patience, this has been an incredible help to me and I am now onto the next piece of the puzzle. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use element-wise operations on vectors:

```
# arbitrary values
azimuths <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)
beamwidths <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

# this means that each of the elements of resulting vector is equal to an element of azimuths vector minus half of corresponding element of beamwidths vector, you can do similarly with two-dimensional structures too
edgesStart <- azimuth - beamwidths/2
edgesEnd <- azimuth + beamwidths/2

matrix(c(edgesStart, edgesEnd), ncol=2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  9.5 10.5
[2,] 19.0 21.0
[3,] 28.5 31.5
[4,] 38.0 42.0
[5,] 47.5 52.5
[6,] 57.0 63.0
```